# cURL To Public Website receiving no SYN_ACK packets?

Tags: php, linux, networking, curl, tcp

I'm writing a script that needs to, very briefly, scrape the URL of a public website. I'm writing the script in PHP, but I've tested from the command line as well and the same problems exist.

Basically, this is the error I get:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I watched this command:

```
netstat -ac 5 |grep tcp
```

and I can see the SYN_SENT packets going outbound (although they appear to be leaving on port 58047 even though I specified port 80 using cURL), but the server never responds with a SYN_ACK.

Using a browser I can view the same exact address quite easily.

They experienced some kind of attack on their servers about a week ago, so I have to imagine they are dropping my packets at the firewall or using iptables, but I'm just trying to send one request.

I've tried sending a browser agent string that I know the server will respond to using cURL, but alas, nothing. The script lives on an AWS EC2 instance.

I'm not even sure what to do as far as eliminating my unknowns. I don't know how to really monitor TCP traffic, or understand what I'm seeing too well, but I'd like to figure this out.

Any advice?

PS: I have confirmed that cURL is working fine. It pulled google.com without any trouble at all.

Comment: What's the URL of the site?

Comment: http://www.fanfiction.net/

Comment: Can you post your `curl` command?

Comment: The command line would be best.

Comment: Here's the command line: curl -# --user-agent 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15' http://www.fanfiction.net/

Comment: Change `fanfiction.net` to `http://www.fanfiction.net/`. You can remove the user agent string as well.

Comment: stackoverflow changed it. It's a fully qualified URL in the command.

Comment: That's interesting. `curl http://www.fanfiction.net/` works just fine for me. Are you using any proxies? What does `curl http://www.fanfiction.net/ --verbose --head` output?

Comment: Hmmm... they must have blacklisted the AWS C-block. I'm not using any proxies. That command generates: "Trying 209.151.227.84..." then "Connection timed out"